# Mercurial shortcut to hsitedit all drafts

Tags: command-line, mercurial

Whenever I need to use `hg histedit`, I do something like this:

1. Using TortoiseHG to determine the lowest level draft number
2. `Hg histedit -r {lowest level draft number}`

This process takes quite a bit of time for something that seems rather common.  Is there a shortcut for this, something like, perhaps `hg histedit -s draft`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mercurial's [revsets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) to accomplish that! To find the rev number of the first draft changeset:

```
hg log -r "first(draft() and ancestors(tip))"
```

I added the `ancestors(tip)` clause since my repo has draft changes on several branches at the moment `:)`.

I believe there is a place in tortoise where you can search using revsets, but I don't use tortoisehg all that often.

Some commands can accept revsets as arguments for the `--rev` switch, but I don't believe it is universal.

Comment: Was having trouble with this, but if you change `ancestor` to `ancestors`, it works on my machine.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Fixed that in the post - `ancestor` is a valid command but has a very different meaning.